# Inavalid Address error while using Google Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api

I am getting a very strange error which is not being discussed anywhere.
I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ajayramesh/social-login-with-omniauth-and-rails-5-0-ad2bbd2a998e) to use google omniauth as a sign in process. The code runs well but after hitting Sign In With Google, the server throws an error of
**IPAddr::InvalidAddressError**

with error happening on the line
*raise InvalidAddressError, "invalid address"*

I have no clue how to solve this. Does Google API's not run with localhost:3000?

Comment: Google API works with localhost. Have you added it to the list of Authorized redirect URIs?

Comment: Yes I have done that. I have followed the tutorial line by line. But still unable to solve it.

Comment: Include all the error logs just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue as with rails server running in proxy enabled network.
This is an issue with `ruby 2.4.0`. It is fixed in `ruby 2.4.2`. 
You can fix it by upgrading ruby version or following method below

Add this line in Gemfile:

```
gem 'no_proxy_fix'
```

Or add this line in *.gemspec:

```
spec.add_dependency 'no_proxy_fix'
```

And add this line to make sure that this code runs before your connection-related code.

```
require 'no_proxy_fix'
```

References:

http://ermaker.github.io/blog/2017/02/06/proxy-error-on-ruby-2.4.0.html

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/556e3da4216c926e71dea9ce4ea4a08dcfdc1275

Hope you find it helpful!